# Sitecore.Context.Site is set for all SPEAK resources

Tags: speak

I've implemented a custom pipeline in `HttpRequestProcessed`. When doing the usual 'bail as soon as possible' setup, I'm checking the following:

```
if (Sitecore.Context.Site == null || 
    !Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsNormal ||
    Sitecore.Context.Site.Name != "my-site")
       return;
```

Its a pipeline that should only run on the website front-end. When testing the back-end I noticed several Sitecore apps such as the `List Manager` were a lot slower or not loading at all completely.

And while debugging, I saw that all calls to `SPEAK` resources continue in my pipeline. Which means that the `Site.Context` is set, and the `Site.Name` also matches.

**Example:** http://my-site.local/-/speak/v1/assets/main.js

Anyone has a clue why this could be happening?

Comment: Might be by design, but I would exclude more requests in your pipeline ;) Start with everything that ends with .js and .css ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at site definitions in vanilla Sitecore, none of them work for `~/speak/v1` virtual folders or just `/`. That's why your site may be matched as the first one.

If you don't want to run your processor for non-item requests best check

```
Sitecore.Context.Item?.Visualization?.Layout != null
```